# ROC curve manual calculation vs. pROC package R

Tags: machine-learning, r, logistic-regression, roc

I want do recreate ROC curve manually on my dataset and compare it to roc function from pROC package in R. I'm using dataset on customer churn `telco.csv` from Kaggle. Data can be found here: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/blastchar/telco-customer-churn?resource=download.

I import data, and change column `Churn` to factor variable with levels `1,0`.

```
telco %>%  mutate(Churn = ifelse(Churn == "Yes",1,0)) -> telco
factor(telco$Churn, levels = c(1,0)) -> telco$Churn
```

For the sake of simplicity, I run logistic regression with only one explanatory variable `MonthlyCharges`.

```
glm(Churn ~ MonthlyCharges, data = telco, family = "binomial") -> model
```

Now, that I have a model, I'll use `roc` function from `pROC` package, and plot the roc curve:

```
roc(telco$Churn, predict(model,telco, type = "response")) -> roc_curve
par(pty = "s")
plot(roc_curve)
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Now, I want to recreate this result manually. For defined thresholds I'll plot TP rate versus FP rate, and calculate sensitivity and specificity using `yardstick` package.

```
model_data <- list()
thrs <- seq(0,1,0.01)
sens <- NULL
FP_rate <- NULL


for (i in seq_along(thrs)) {
  model_data_i <- augment(model, type.predict = "response") %>%
    mutate(pred = ifelse(.fitted > thrs[i], 1, 0)) %>%
    mutate(pred = factor(pred, levels = c(1, 0)))
  
  model_data[[i]] <- model_data_i
  
  sens[i] <- yardstick::sensitivity(model_data_i, Churn, pred) %>% pull(.estimate)
  FP_rate[i] <- 1 - yardstick::specificity(model_data_i, Churn, pred) %>% pull(.estimate)
}

tibble(sens,FP_rate) ->  roc_data

ggplot(roc_data, aes(FP_rate, sens)) + geom_line(size = 1.5, color = "blue") +
  geom_abline(intercept =  0, slope = 1, linetype = "dashed") +
  coord_fixed(ratio = 1) + 
  theme_minimal()
```

Here is the result:

[image]

These two graph look inverse, and they provide significantly different AUC values. When I plot `sens` on x-axis and FP rate on y-axis, the graphs are the same, but then it doesn't make sense to me.

Also, when I look at ratio of TP and FP rates, there are more times where this ratio is below 1, which give more evidence to my manually calculated ROC curve.

```
tibble(sens,FP_rate) %>% mutate(ratio = sens/FP_rate) -> roc_data
```

Even if I use thresholds using `roc_curve$thresholds` I get the same result.

Where am I making a mistake?

Answer (score 1):

If the `pROC` function yields a ROC curve with an area under the curve less than $1/2,$ `pROC` will flip the labels and recalculate the ROC curve and the area underneath it, and this is the curve that is plotted. I disagree with the decision to make this default behavior, but there is an argument to keep the function from doing this.

`pROC::roc(…, direction = “<“)`

There’s nothing wrong with this kind of [calibration step](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/565642/247274), but I disagree with the default behavior of calibrating automatically and without user knowledge, possibly leading the user into believing that a model is good when it is terrible, even if a second stage of the prediction pipeline (calibration) could lead to good predictions.